# Jasper Report with Scriplet is not working when deployed on Jasper Server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to Jasper reporting and I have a report with a simple scriplet that only return a string. When previewing it with Jasper studio 6.5.0, I was able to see the results but when I try deploy the same report on my local jasper server, it throws the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: <class> cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractScriptlet
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.scriptlets.DefaultScriptletFactory.getScriptlet(DefaultScriptletFactory.java:109)
    ... 178 more]]
```

I am running the server on Glassfish 4.1.1, included the scriplet jar file in the lib folder and changed the import in the scriplet according to https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/classcast-exception-when-running-report-containing-scriptlet

Below is my test scriplet:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;

public class DemoScriplet extends JRDefaultScriptlet{

public String getHello() throws JRScriptletException{
    return "This is from a scriplet!";
}
```

Has anyone else encountered this error before?

Comment: What version of JRS are you using?

Comment: I'm using JRS 6.4.2. I installed it using the war file distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I found an alternative to this problem. Instead of added the scriplet to the lib, I've added it as a report resource instead. Also, I have found a video for reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9Hv6DrwrhQ

Hope this helps someone.